# PageExpiredException, migration to wicket 1.5 not working

Tags: java, exception, migration, wicket, wicket-1.5

I am trying to server a particular error page when session timeouts to my users.
For this i configured the error page on my Application's init method.
But this thing is not working.

I set up the session tiemout in 1 minute, after that nothing happen, I went through the logs, but wicket didn't throw any PageExpiredException.

When session timeouts wicket simply logs it as:
Session unbound: C061F4F21C41EDF13C66795DAC9EDD02
Removing data for pages in session with id 'C061F4F21C41EDF13C66795DAC9EDD02'

this is my init method in my customApplication

```
protected void init() {
    super.init();

    this.getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(SessionExpiredPage.class);

    ...
    ...
}
```

my SessionExpiredPage.class

```
public class SessionExpiredPage extends TecnoAccionPage {

    public SessionExpiredPage() {
        this.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.add(new Label("title", "Sesión Expirada"));
        CSSLoader.get().appendCssUntil(this, SessionExpiredPage.class);
    }
}
```

And i have a custom implementation of AbstractRequestCycleListener i override the OnException method But, when my session expire, I never pass in the "onException".

Thank You, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there is no `PageExpiredException` thrown by wicket, while it can reconstruct requested page, even if the session was expired.

So, there is another way to deal with this problem.
You have to override `onRequestHandlerResolved` method in your `AbstractRequestCycleListener`, to catch all incoming requests, and check there if incoming session id is outdated.

To check this, you must have list of the expired sessions in your app and catch unbound event to manage them.

This is going to be something like that:

```
public class YourApp extends WebApplication {

    //synchronized list with ids
    private List<String> unboundSessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();

        this.getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(SessionExpiredPage.class);

        //add request listener
        getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
            public void onRequestHandlerResolved(RequestCycle cycle, IRequestHandler handler) {
                if (handler instanceof IPageRequestHandler) {
                    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest();

                    String sessionId = request.getRequestedSessionId();
                    //check whether the requested session has expired
                    boolean expired = sessionId != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();

                    //if session is not valid and it was really expired
                    if (expired && unboundSessions.contains(sessionId)) {
                        //then remove it from unbound list
                        unboundSessions.remove(sessionId);
                        //and throw exception
                        throw new PageExpiredException("Expired");
                    }
                }
                super.onRequestHandlerResolved(cycle, handler);
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    //this method called when any session is invalidated, so check your manual invalidating calls (if you ever do them)
    @Override
    public void sessionUnbound(String sessionId) {
        super.sessionUnbound(sessionId);
        if (!unboundSessions.contains(sessionId)) {
            unboundSessions.add(sessionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Unbound sessions list needs for us to know, that user's session is really expired, since the `expired` variable in our listener could be also `true` when user just openes our site after redeploy, for example. His session is taken from his cookies and it could be already expired, but that would be weird to redirect him to `SessionExpiredPage` immediately.

It looks like a workaround, but it should work.